# Javascript Regular expression : ^[^/\s/]+[a-z]{1,}[0-9]*[\-\_]*[^\/][^/\s/]$

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to create a regular expression which will:

- not contain any space and special characters except "-" and "_"
- it should contain at least one alphabet character

The regular expression I created is:

```
^[^/\s/]+[a-z]{1,}[0-9]*[\-\_]*[^\/][^/\s/]$
```

It only only matches if my string contains at least 4 characters, including 1 alphabet. I tried it on https://regex101.com/#javascript Can someone help me what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Will appreciate if someone can help me for regular expression resources where I can learn and master it.

Comment: Basically you want something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068843/password-validation-regex. Or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370015/regular-expression-for-password-validation. Or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21760692/regular-expression-for-password-validation-c-sharp...

Comment: @Rawing Thanks, I will try something with this. Just FYI, this will be basically a string which I want to append with URL. so I want to allow only "-" & "_" not even "/"

Comment: Can someone let me know, why it is downvoted?

Comment: @RohitVerma Can you answer the question in these comments?  Which is the correct criteria for your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to learn about [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). One solution to your problem is:

```
/(?=^[\w-]{4,}$)(.*[a-z].*)/gmi
```

- `(?=^[\w-]{4,}$)` will assert that you input will contains only chars in the range a-z, digit, `_` and , `-` with a length of *at least* 4.
- `(.*[a-z].*)` ensure that there will be *at least* one char in the range a-z.

See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iN8eA1/1)

Answer (score 1):

Using fundamental regex primitives, you can use this:

```
/^[0-9_-]*[a-z]+[0-9a-z_-]*$/i
```

It works correctly with these sample input strings:

- 999c123-
- a123-88asd
- 9923--_b
- B
- 99-luftballoons
- Z8f

And does not match these strings:

- 999
- -51-
- -*-*-_-

It's fast and will work in pretty much every regex engine, even non-standard (non-extended) grep.

Comment: Did you tested it?

Comment: Unfortunately this won't check for minimum length (of 4) requirement

Comment: I read the description differently.  My understanding is that his doesn't work, because it requires a minimum of 4 characters, but he wants it to require only 1.  One of us may have misunderstood the question, and I'm not sure which.

Comment: Well... You might be right! Let's wait for op to clarify